# SimpleXML Xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

XML file can be seen below:

#

How can I code it so the product and offer data is displayed in order.

Currently i have tried the following code:

```
foreach ($xml->GeneralSearchResponse->categories->category->items->xpath('/product | /offer') as $product) 
{

    print $product->name;
}
```

This however does not show any data.

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Which kind of order? And which XML element(s) represent a product and which an offer? - And what have you tried so far, please add your code and show with which part of your xpath you have a problem in specific.

Comment: Hi the <product></product> and <offer></offer> also it can be in any order.

Comment: I have tried:

foreach ($xml->GeneralSearchResponse->categories->category->items->xpath('/product | /offer') as $product) 
{

 print $product->name;
}

Comment: Please add that in full written sentences to your question. You can edit it. Also your XML is pretty lengthy (what you linked). If you add an excerpt of it which shows what you're concerned about (next to the code you have so far), your question would highly improve. Asking the right question is near to having the answer ;)

Comment: Also it might help if you *explain* why you have a problem to formulate the xpath expression you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The XML pointed to by the provided link is not well-formed**. Most probably you get an XML parsing error.

More specifically, any `&somename=` must be changed to `&amp;somename=`.

There also seem to be other severe, illegal syntax problems.

Comment: Yes, I just get no data out from the for each statement.

Comment: @JackTheJack: Therefore, the problem isn't in XPath at all. To start with, correct the data so that you have a well-formed XML document.

Comment: Additionally I think it's worth to notice to do the xpath *before* the foreach and on the whole document. That way the responsibility is more clear: the xpath expression to get the list of nodes, the foreach to iterate over it. Debugging get's easier as well.